# How do I tell a script to wait for a process to start accepting requests on a port?

Tags: shell, networking, process, open-files

I need a command that will wait for a process to start accepting requests on a specific port.

Is there something in linux that does that?

```
while (checkAlive -host localhost -port 13000 == false)
  do some waiting

...
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The best test to see if a server is accepting connections is to actually try connecting. Use a regular client for whatever protocol your server speaks and try a no-op command.

If you want a lightweight TCP or UDP client you can drive simply from the shell, use [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat). How to program a conversation depends on the protocol; many protocols have the server close the connection on a certain input, and netcat will then exit.

```
while ! echo exit | nc localhost 13000; do sleep 10; done
```

You can also tell netcat to exit after establishing the connection. It returns 1 if there's no connection and 0 if there is so we negate its output. Depending on your version of netcat, it may support one or both of the following commands:

```
while ! nc -z localhost 13000 </dev/null; do sleep 10; done
while ! nc -q 1 localhost 13000 </dev/null; do sleep 10; done
```

An alternative approach is to wait for the server process to open a listening socket.

```
while netstat -lnt | awk '$4 ~ /:13000$/ {exit 1}'; do sleep 10; done
```

If you are on Mac OS, netstat uses a slightly different output format, so you would want the following intead:

```
while netstat -lnt | awk '$4 ~ /\.13000$/ {exit 1}'; do sleep 10; done
```

Or you might want to target a specific process ID:

```
while ! lsof -n -Fn -p $pid | grep -q '^n.*:13000$'; do sleep 10; done
```

I can't think of any way to react to the process starting to listen to the socket (which would avoid a polling approach) short of using `ptrace`.

Comment: I think netcat is the answer, so thank you.  To clarify, what I'm trying to do is write a script as part of a load balancing procedure.  I need to start a process, wait for it to accept requests on the port and then shutdown the original.  If there are better ways of doing this, rather than writing my own script, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Will: That's a very different question! I've written a different answer.

Comment: I like netcat solution too.  I have a script using `nc -w 2 </dev/null >/dev/null` — if the connection takes more than 2 seconds, it times out and fails — which is handy for my usage.

Comment: FYI, I can't get the 'while nc -q 1 localhost 13000 </dev/null; do sleep 10; done' one to work. It just returns immediately. The first one works fine though. Thanks!

Comment: @Flyte `nc -q 1 localhost 13000 </dev/null` returns immediately if no server is listening, but it returns with an error code, so the loop makes it sleep and try again a few seconds later.

Comment: @Gilles It's for this reason that we need a ! in there to negate its output. I've submitted an edit to fix it :)

Comment: Is there a reason you use `! nc -q 1 localhost 13000 </dev/null` instead of `! nc -z localhost 13000 &> /dev/null`? `-z` seems to do exactly what you want - check if a port is listening.

Comment: @dimo414 Portability: traditional `nc` doesn't have `-z`.

Comment: OSX's `nc` doesn't have `-q`, but it does have `-z` :)

Answer (score 21):

If you have bash and coreutils (e.g. timeout, sleep), but not nc/lsof/netstat, you can use this solution which uses bash magic tcp sockets:

```
while ! timeout 1 bash -c "echo > /dev/tcp/localhost/13000"; do sleep 10; done
```

Comment: To elaborate, Bash has the optional feature of connecting to TCP sockets using "network redirections" -- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections

Comment: I wonder under which conditions it'll block...

Answer (score 18):

Following the [previous example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149053/217844) with `bash` tcp sockets magic, here is an enhanced version which waits for connection during limited amount of time.

```
timeout 15 bash -c 'until echo > /dev/tcp/localhost/13000; do sleep 0.5; done'
```

The difference is that if connection wasn't available during `15s`, - it won't loop forever but exit with the error code.

This is useful in init scripts to wait for service readiness/availability after startup.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a utility to wait for a port to open, it can also check MySQL, PostgreSQL, Redis and etc availability.

```
# Checking TCP port
wait4x tcp localhost:8080

# Checking TCP port with specific timeout (5 Minutes)
wait4x tcp localhost:8080 -t 5m
```

It's open source and available at https://github.com/atkrad/wait4x. Hopefully others will find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

I used this to wait for a couple of ports to be open, without netcat:

```
while (! (: </dev/tcp/localhost/27017) &> /dev/null || ! (: </dev/tcp/localhost/9200) &> /dev/null); do
    sleep 2;
done
```

Change `localhost` and the ports as needed.