# Run a command in parallel and wait for specific output

Tags: bash

I'm a newbie on bash scripts and would like to ask what's best/easiest way to achieve the following:

1. run a command in parallel (e.g. run a nodejs web app); the output of the command should be written to console as usual
2. wait until a specific string occurs in output (e.g. "DB initialized")
3. then run another command (e.g. command to create some DB data)
4. afterwards wait until the command from 1. ends

This is my current script that does the waiting by `sleep` but of course this is just a workaround:

```
# parallel command
npm run start &

# wait for specific output
sleep 15s

# do something
node_modules/.bin/knex seed:run

# wait for parallel command to exit
wait
```

I found a [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21002153/1063673) but the output of command executed in parallel is not printed to console I think.

Background: The script is the entry point of a docker image based on the alpine variant of nodejs image.

Comment: Do you have specific reasons for running `npm run start` asynchronously? Are you starting several concurrent instances of it? If yes, will "DB initialized" be emitted several times? And will it be required to trigger `node_modules/.bin/knex` every time?

Comment: @fra-san I run it asynchronously to do the knex command when DB is initialized. It's only one instance of web app. The knex command should be executed one time per script run and "DB intialized" will occur only one time. The script is ran as entry point for a docker image.

Comment: You may also be interested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5277/315749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible ways to achieve that:

```bsh
npm run start |
  tee /dev/tty | {
    grep -q "DB initialized" && node_modules/.bin/knex seed:run
    cat >/dev/null
  }
```

`tee /dev/tty` duplicates `npm`'s output and sends it to both the terminal and the command that follows in the pipeline.

`grep -q` silently exits at the first match with `0` as its status; this triggers the next command in the "AND" list (`node_modules/.bin/knex seed:run`).

`cat /dev/null` is there just to keep the pipe open: `grep -q` exiting would cause `tee` to receive a SIGPIPE signal when trying to write further data to the pipe and exit in turn. This `cat` prevents that by reading from the pipe until `npm` and `tee` exit.

There is no need to run `npm` asynchronously: all the components of a pipeline run concurrently and the only thing you want to ensure here is that none of them exits before the slower one completes.

Note that `/dev/tty` may not be available if this snippet is run in the context of a process with no controlling terminal. An alternative, assuming the standard streams are also accessible in the `/dev/fd/n` form on your system, is:

```bsh
npm run start | {
  tee /dev/fd/9 | {
    grep -q "DB initialized" && node_modules/.bin/knex seed:run
    cat >/dev/null
  }
} 9>&1
```

The `9` file descriptor (arbitrarily chosen) is created as a copy of the file the whole pipeline's standard output is connected to, making it available as `/dev/fd/9` to any command in the outer `{ ... }` list.